# 1995 Chevrolet Blazer - Spits and sputters over 45 mph

Tags: engine, chevrolet, rough-idle, blazer, stall

When my truck idles it's smooth but when I get on road and the engine gets up to operating temperature it spits and sputters. When I pull into the driveway, it cuts off.  I have replaced the fuel pump, fuel filter, ignition coil, ignition module and ECU. I pulled the EGR valve and cleaned it. Still no change in running conditions.  Does anyone have any insight into this problem?

Comment: Any codes in the computer?

Comment: Does this car have an O2 sensor? If so, any idea about its condition?

Comment: OP did you get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 1):

It will be one of important sensors. it might be RPM sensor, Cam position sensor, Throttle position sensor, Air/fuel sensor... You need to plug your truck to a right laptop which can show all the sensors how they work. Most likely it is something that causes ignition timing fault (not fuel).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding some heet? sometimes it fixes the most trivial things. maybe there is some water in your gas tank. our engine used to rev excessively. we added 2 bottles of heat and then it would go away. hope that helps!

Comment: Downvoter should comment. I have a '97 Blazer and I too add a bottle of Heet every now and then when I experience a little rough running  and it's been effective. So +1. However, my guess about the downvote is...the OP mentioned their missing occurs at running temperature, and the rough running I'm thinking of is likely due to water in the fuel, which results in misfiring regardless of engine temperature.